# I'm using VS code and I'm really new here. I was making an AI using Python. If someone can assist me regarding an issue please

Tags: visual-studio, pyaudio, modulenotfounderror

I'm getting this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\PYTHON\Python\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 108, in 
    get_pyaudio
        import pyaudio
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "d:\PYTHON\Python Programs\Jarvis\jarvis.py", line 48, in <module>
        takeCommand()
      File "d:\PYTHON\Python Programs\Jarvis\jarvis.py", line 29, in takeCommand
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
      File "D:\PYTHON\Python\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 79, in 
    __init__    
         self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
      File "D:\PYTHON\Python\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 110, in 
    get_pyaudio
         raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
    AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

How to solve this issue? I'm new to these things.
Python version 3.9.2
Using Visual Code Studio

Comment: Whenever "No module named 'xxx'" occurs, try `pip install xxx`. You have quite a lot to learn so guides like https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide should be your start.

Comment: @LexLi I did but this error occured:
**Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"d:\python\python.exe"  "D:\PYTHON\Python\Scripts\pip.exe" install pyaudio': The system cannot find the file specified.**

Comment: @LexLi My pip command is also not working but I downloaded two modules like. 1. Open Python. 2. Import pip. 3. **pip.main(['install', 'pyaudio'])** but the error for pyaudio is as above.

Comment: I guess you have some messed up python installation (maybe two different versions in the path or something). Make sure you have only one python installation.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you will have to use the python executable that matches the one of your current "environment", otherwise it will not get picked up. You may also want to provide more context to your question, like what OS you are using, whether you are using a virtual environment, like with `conda` or `venv` to keep the dependencies better managed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.